# JAVA - Creating X509 certificate from byte array

Tags: java, arrays, x509certificate

my server application send a certificate (by an array of byte) to the client who have to recreate the original certificate using  the byte[] array.
How can i do this?

If i use the certificateFactory i can only pass by parameter an InputStream, which is not what i need.

Anybody can help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going from a `byte[]` to an `InputStream` is easy - just wrap the array in a `ByteArrayInputStream`. If you've tried that and it didn't work, please provide more information.